# Tomcat 7 ignore application context.xml

Tags: tomcat, datasource, context.xml

Is it possible to tell *Tomcat 7* to ignore datasources defined in application *context.xml* (located in META-INF).

Goal is to necessary define datasources at server level.

Comment: Would removing the datasources from the application context be possible?

Comment: yes it is possible , but we try to find a generic solution for all applications.